# Print the details of a file in a format like "Jun 19 10:08" in Linux ubuntu under C

Tags: c, linux, file, ubuntu, io

I'm trying to present the details of any file under `Ubuntu` using `C` .

For example , if I'm looking for a file / folder called `12` , I get :

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./exer4 . 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 1000 1000 4096 2012-06-19 10:08 
drwxrwxr-x 3 1000 1000 4096 2012-06-16 14:09
```

But I want to display it like that :

```
a@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ find . -name 12 -exec ls \-lnd {} \; | sort
drwxrwxr-x 3 1000 1000 4096 Jun 16 14:09 
drwxrwxr-x 3 1000 1000 4096 Jun 19 10:08
```

Meaning , I want to change this : `2012-06-19 10:08` to that `Jun 19 10:08` , or this

`2012-06-16 14:09` to that  `Jun 16 14:09` .

I'm using the following method for presenting the details of any file :

```
void displayFileProperties(struct stat* file,char*  outputProperties)
{


    char partOfOutput[BUFFER];
    mode_t mode = file->st_mode;
    struct tm* time;
    int month, day, hour, min;

    // First take care of the file details , e.g permission

    // this is a regular file
    if (S_ISREG(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"-");

    // the is a pipe file
    else if (S_ISFIFO(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"p");

    // for a link file
    else if (S_ISLNK(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"l");

    // for a directory file
    else if (S_ISDIR(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"d");

    // this is for a socket file
    else if (S_ISSOCK(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"s");

    // for a block device file
    else if (S_ISBLK(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"b");

    // and this is one for a character device file
    else if (S_ISCHR(mode)) strcat(outputProperties,"c");


    // Permissions

    (mode & S_IRUSR)? strcat(outputProperties,"r"): strcat(outputProperties,"-");
    (mode & S_IWUSR)? strcat(outputProperties,"w"): strcat(outputProperties,"-");
    (mode & S_IXUSR)? strcat(outputProperties,"x"): strcat(outputProperties,"-");


    // Group permission

    (mode & S_IRGRP) ?strcat(outputProperties,"r"):strcat(outputProperties,"-");
    (mode & S_IWGRP) ?strcat(outputProperties,"w"):strcat(outputProperties,"-");
    (mode & S_IXGRP) ?strcat(outputProperties,"x"):strcat(outputProperties,"-");


    (mode & S_IROTH)? strcat(outputProperties,"r"):strcat(outputProperties,"-");
    (mode & S_IWOTH) ?strcat(outputProperties,"w"):strcat(outputProperties,"-");
    (mode & S_IXOTH) ?strcat(outputProperties,"x"):strcat(outputProperties,"-");



    //print other information

    //print num of hard link
    sprintf(partOfOutput," %d ",file->st_nlink);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    //print num of hard link
    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d ",file->st_uid);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    //print num of hard link
    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d ",file->st_gid);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    //print num of hard link
    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d ",(int) file->st_size);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);


    // From here take care of the time properties

    time = localtime(&file->st_mtim);

    month = time->tm_mon + 1;
    day = time->tm_mday;
    hour = time->tm_hour;
    min = time->tm_min;

    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d-",time->tm_year + 1900);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    if(month < 10)
        strcat(outputProperties,"0");

    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d-",month);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    if(day < 10)
        strcat(outputProperties,"0");

    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d ",day);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    if(hour < 10)
        strcat(outputProperties,"0");

    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d:",hour);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

    if(min < 10)
      strcat(outputProperties,"0");

    sprintf(partOfOutput,"%d ",min);
    strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);

}
```

How can I do that ? I'm almost sure it requires some minor changes , however I've searched over
the web but found nothing that can clarify this .

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `strftime`:

```
time = localtime(&file->st_mtim);
strftime(partOfOutput, BUFFER, "%b %d %H:%M", time);
```

Check the [documentation for `strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime). It can be used to solve most of the problems with date and time formatting.

Comment: Thanks ,but it still shows the same output .I've added to line you mentioned at the end of the function above ,however still the same output . Any idea what went wrong ?

Comment: You will still need to append the `partOfOutput`: `strcat(outputProperties,partOfOutput);`

Answer (score 4):

The `strftime()` function is very flexible with date formatting. http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime

```
strftime(partOfOutput, BUFFER, "%b %d %H:%M", time);
```

Comment: No need to use leave space for null-terminator (`BUFFER-1`) as `strftime` accepts array length as `max` (not the number of actual characters).

Comment: @Nicht Verstehen - I was uncertain what would happen if there was not enough room for the NULL -- either it just got ignored, or the string was not written at all. You're correct; it causes the string to not be touched at all, so I've revised my answer. Thanks.